# How does deleting a question affect my status?

Tags: support, post-ban

I asked a question that seemed like a good one at the time, but it was put on hold by a mod because it was too vague. Which was actually a fair point; I could not replicate the issue in a clean solution as well, and the subject was vague, so I opted to delete it.

Now I know that asking too many junk questions can get you banned from asking questions, but how much does asking a question like that affect your standing when you choose to delete the question?

P.S. No rep changes occurred, because the question was neither up- nor downvoted; it is not a question regarding rep, but more of the background calculation that can get you banned from asking questions.

Comment: Such details about the question ban algorithm are not publicly disclosed.  We know that deleted questions (even without a negative score) count against you (quite a bit), but we don't know *precisely* to what degree.

Comment: @Servy I was aware of that myself (still chose to delete it, because the question was pointless), but I guess I would at least like to know how will I know when I am starting to borderline.

Comment: You won't know.

Comment: We don't want people to ride the line, so it's intentionally blurry.

Comment: One or two should not really matter, as long as your other questions are good and have some upvotes.

Comment: Here's an open question to the people who do manage the algorithm.  If you do reveal details of how the algorithm works, do you think that people will be able to use that information to continue to post low quality content?  Do you think that they actually will post lower quality content if they know how the question ban works?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think folks should be encouraged to clean up after themselves if they agree with criticism, rather than waiting for others to do it to/for them.